# what is a good wordpress gallery plugin that uses jquery lightbox?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, image-gallery

i am using WP Photo Album and i like how it has albums but i am having trouble trying to make it work with lightbox. i've manually put lightbox in and it didnt work then i put lightbox as a plugin and when i click on one of the images in the album it doesnt show.

this is what the images in the album look like

```
<div class="thumbs">
<ul>
<li>
<a class="img" rel="lightbox[26]" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/photos/?album=1&amp;photo=1"><img alt="*" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wppa/thumbs/1.jpg"></a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="img" rel="lightbox[26]" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/photos/?album=1&amp;photo=1"><img alt="*" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wppa/thumbs/1.jpg"></a>
</li>

<li>
<a class="img" rel="lightbox[26]" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/photos/?album=1&amp;photo=1"><img alt="*" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/wppa/thumbs/1.jpg"></a>
</li>

</ul>
<div style="clear: both;">
</div>
```

i noticed the problem is at http://localhost:8888/wordpress/photos/?album=1&photo=1 the url doesnt have an image in it. thing is if any of you know this plugin how can i show the image url instead of that url? the function that its using is this

```
<?php wppa_photo_page_url(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice and easy one and uses Colorbox which is a little nicer than Lightbox imo

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-colorbox/